# Force Wordpress images to have same height despite upload dimensions using Bootstrap

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, image-size

I have some code to output images in Wordpress like this...

```
<div class="col-md-2">

<?php $image = get_field('artist_photo');
       if( !empty($image) ): 
        // thumbnail
        $size = 'medium';
        $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
       ?>
<img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" class="img-responsive" />

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is, all of the images have different heights (based on their proportions at original upload}.

Is it possible to make them have a uniform height whilst remaining responsive?

Comment: It would help if you explain the layout you're going for. That will make it easier to propose some CSS that will achieve your goal.

Comment: layout is as above - Bootstrap 6 columns. an image in each column. At the moment if I upload 6 different images, they all have different heights based on original image size. I need every image in every column to have matching heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to constrain the height of an image in CSS.

First, you can set a maximum height. So something like:

```
.col-md-2 img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Second, you can display the image as a background image and then use the `background-size` property to constrain it. In your markup display the image using:

```
<div class="image" style="background: url(<?php echo $thumb; ?>) no-repeat center;" />
```

And style it like so:

```
.col-md-2 {
  height: 300px;
}

.col-md-2 div.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%; // for example, assuming you want 4 images per row
  background-size: constrain;
}
```

I'm not sure how this will work in the context of bootstrap, but option 2 might be your only option if you can't specify an explicit height for the image or its parent.

There are more devils in the details and the specifics will depend on your situation, but hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Greg - was trying to avoid doing it as a background image, but that seems like the most effective way.